# Populating a form field in a view

Tags: python, django

I am working on an imageboard application, which has two views. An **index view** and a **thread view**.

Views.py

```
def ThreadView(request, thread_id):
template = loader.get_template('thread.html')
form = MessageForm(request.POST)
if request.method == 'POST':
    #form = MessageForm(initial={'thread': thread_id})
    #form.fields['thread'].initial = thread_id
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        form = MessageForm()

    else:
        form = MessageForm()        

context = {
    'message': Thread.objects.get(id=thread_id),
    'replies': Message.objects.all().filter(thread=thread_id),
    'form':form
}
return HttpResponse(template.render(context, request))
```

Models.py

```
class Thread(models.Model):
    msg = models.TextField(max_length=9001)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

class Message(models.Model):
    msg = models.TextField(max_length=9001)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    thread = models.ForeignKey('Thread', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Forms.py

```
class ThreadForm(forms.ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = Thread
    fields = [
        'msg'
    ]

class MessageForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Message
        fields = [
            'msg'
        ]
```

The problem is this: Message model has a foreign key to Thread model, and when I am posting to a certain thread, I need to prepopulate the "thread"-field in Message model with thread_id in views.py (because a message has to belong to a certain thread).
The two lines that I have commented out are my attempts of passing the field value to a form, both unsuccessful.

Is this even possible in function-based views? (Python 3, Django 2.0)

I'm sorry if I missed something, I'm really tired of coding all day. Feel free to ask me if I failed to post some crucial information.

Comment: Add a hidden input field to your template which pre-populates the thread_id?

Comment: Great idea, I will implement it if I cant find a way to do it in a view, which I think would be a better way.

Comment: Of course setting it directly is possible in any kind of view, function-based or class-based. There are hundreds of questions on this subject. Just exclude the field from the form, do `form.save(commit=False)`, then set the FK on the result.

Comment: Also, you must always redirect on a successful submission; you shouldn't be re-instantiating the form and falling through to the render in that case.

Answer (score 0):

I got it working. Thank you for your replies!

Views.py:

```
def ThreadView(request, thread_id):
template = loader.get_template('thread.html')
#form = MessageForm(request.POST or None, initial={'thread': thread_id})
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = MessageForm(request.POST or None, initial={'thread': thread_id})
    if form.is_valid():
        instance = form.save(commit=False)
        instance.thread_id=thread_id
        instance.save()
        return redirect(ThreadView, thread_id)

else:
    form = MessageForm(request.POST or None, initial={'thread': thread_id})        

context = {
    'message': Thread.objects.get(id=thread_id),
    'replies': Message.objects.all().filter(thread=thread_id),
    'thread_id': thread_id,
    'form':form
}
return HttpResponse(template.render(context, request))
```